# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hibernate.dto.Employee

Tags: hibernate

I have Employee class as below with OneToMany relationship with Education

```
@Entity
    public class Employee {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int empId;
        private String empName;
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date empDob;
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date empDoj;
        private Long empPhone;
        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)

       //setter and getters
}

@Entity
public class Education {
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer aadharNum;
    private String collegeName;
    private String schoolName;
    private String companyName;

    // setter and getter

}
        public class HibernateTest {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                    Employee employee=new Employee();
                    employee.setEmpName("Sri");
                    employee.setEmpId(7664);
                    employee.setEmpDob(new java.util.Date());
                    employee.setEmpDoj(new java.util.Date());
                    employee.setEmpPhone(8102087655l);
                    Education education=new Education();
                    education.setSchoolName("Neo Royal School");
                    education.setCollegeName("IIT Gu");
                    education.setCompanyName("Insys");
                    Education education2=new Education();
                    education2.setSchoolName("Royal School");
                    education2.setCollegeName("IIT Hyd");
                    education2.setCompanyName("IM");
                    employee.getEducation().add(education);
                    employee.getEducation().add(education2);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
                    session.beginTransaction();
                    session.persist(employee);
                    session.getTransaction().commit();
                    session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you manually assigned an id to your employee entity that isn't yet managed by Hibernate. 
It should work when you remove this `employee.setEmpId(7664);`
Hibernate will then auto-generate an ID for you (because of the `@GeneratedValue`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that for your empId you are using the @GeneratedValue annotation. This means that when you are persisting a new entity, the id field should be left blank and you have to let the jpa provider do fill that in.

So either remove the @GeneratedValue

```
@Id
private int empId;
```

or do not set the empId explicitly